# How to install GLM on MinGW64 in Windows

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, mingw-w64, glm-math

I am getting an error:

```
mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

...when installing GLM.

I have downloaded the latest GLM from [here](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/releases). I am trying to copy the header files to path `C:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32`. I go to the folder that contains `CMakeLists.txt` file and execute the following commands:

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -S . -B . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32
mingw32-make all
mingw32-make install
```

The first two commands worked fine but the third one gave me the error. Could anybody help me with this error?

Comment: Installing headers and libraries directly to your compiler installation directories is a terrible terrible idea. Do not do this.

Comment: As for the actual error you reported: impossible to say without seeing the full CMake output.

Comment: `-S . -B .` This is also terrible practice

Comment: Installation support of GLM has been [added](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/commit/6059c5767b8be1fdaf7b4c8bf6f435ee9f7e5f0c) in 2021, but all assets have been created in 2020. So none of the files to download has installation support. If you want to install GLM, then clone the master branch.

Comment: [tag:glm] != [tag:glm-math]